# Can't save data for Address field

Tags: nodes

I am trying to save data programmatically to an address field from the Address module.

I am not successful.

First, when I dsm() a node with the address field filled out, it looks like this:

```
        [field_addr] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [langcode] => 
                                [country_code] => US
                                [administrative_area] => CA
                                [locality] => San Diego
                                [dependent_locality] => 
                                [postal_code] => 91945
                                [sorting_code] => 
                                [address_line1] => 123 main st
                                [address_line2] => apt 2
                                [organization] => 
                                [given_name] => 
                                [additional_name] => 
                                [family_name] => 
                            )

                    )

            )
```

However, no matter how I try to save it to my node, it doesn't work.

I create an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [x-default] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address_line1] => Australian Club
                    [address_line2] => Royal Lane
                    [locality] => Sydney
                    [administrative_area] => NSW
                    [country] => Australia
                )

        )

)
```

Let's say with the name, `$address_save`

And then do the following:

```
$node->set('field_addr', $address_save);
```

No luck. My node saves with other fields, but this one doesn't. I've also tried it without the x-default key around it as well as without a delta, but neither of those work either.

How can I save values to an Address field inside of a node?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was due to Drupal failing silently (or obfuscating the error - maybe because I was running this in cron) but it was due to the address not having all of the required fields set to the correct values for the country in question - mainly using the actual country name instead of the country code.

Once the country code was swapped in it worked. I switched the country around to the country code like this:

```
function MY_MODULE_get_country_code($country) {
  $countries = MY_MODULE_country_list();
  $flipped_countries = array_flip($countries);
  $country_code = $flipped_countries[$country];
  return $country_code;
}

function MY_MODULE_country_list() {
  $countries = \Drupal\Core\Locale\CountryManager::getStandardList();
  foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
    $countries[$key] = $value->__toString();
  }
  return $countries;
}
```

It worked correctly.

Comment: Would have been great if you posted your final solution. :(